# Return Currency format

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table that does a multiplication of qty by price returning a line item total then a total for all the line items.

I need the results to be in two decimal places. (bonus points if there is a way to return with the dollar sign but from what I can find that isn't an option.)

Scripts I am using below.
I am attempting to use the .toFixed(2) But can't seem to find where to put it correctly without cracking my current scripts. (Self taught so please dumb it down for me :) )

```
<script>
function total_amount(){
        var table = document.getElementById('line_item');
        for(var i=1;i<table.rows.length;i++){
            qty = table.rows[i].cells[1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value
            unit = table.rows[i].cells[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value
            table.rows[i].cells[3].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = qty * unit;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I have a separate script for the total and it is not working. Advice?

'<script type="text/javascript"> function findTotal(){ var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty'); var tot=0; for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){ if(parseInt(arr[i].value)) tot += parseInt(arr[i].value).toFixed(2); } document.getElementById('total').value = tot; } </script>'

Answer (score 2):

You can use the internationalization (i18n) currency formatter:

```js
const cf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD'
});

function total_amount() {
  const table = document.getElementById('line_item');
  let i, qty, unit;
  for (i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    qty = table.rows[i].cells[1].querySelector('input').valueAsNumber;
    unit = table.rows[i].cells[2].querySelector('input').valueAsNumber;
    table.rows[i].cells[3].querySelector('input').value = cf.format(qty * unit);
  }
}

total_amount();
```

```html
<table id="line_item">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Unit Price</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Soap</td>
    <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" value="4.99" step="0.01" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" disabled /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Chips</td>
    <td><input type="number" value="2" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" value="2.99" step="0.01" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" disabled /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also, you should separate your table head and body. This way you don't need to arbitrarily skip the first row.

```js
const cf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD'
});

function total_amount() {
  const table = document.getElementById('line_item');
  let i, qty, unit;
  [...table.tBodies[0].rows].forEach(row => {
    qty = row.cells[1].querySelector('input').valueAsNumber;
    unit = row.cells[2].querySelector('input').valueAsNumber;
    row.cells[3].querySelector('input').value = cf.format(qty * unit);
  });
}

total_amount();
```

```html
<table id="line_item">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Soap</td>
      <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="4.99" step="0.01" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" disabled /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Chips</td>
      <td><input type="number" value="2" /></td>
      <td><input type="number" value="2.99" step="0.01" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" disabled /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```